# Why im getting "ComputerVisionOcrErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'"

Tags: c#, .net-core, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to test the Computer Vision SDK for .NET.
For that i've created a Computer vision resource in azure.

I create a project in .NET6 and follow the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to implement the api call.

But when i reach the code line:

```
var textHeaders = await client.ReadAsync(urlFile);
```

i'm getting the exception:
ComputerVisionOcrErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

This is the complete code:

```
public static void ComputerVisionPOC()
        {
            // Add your Computer Vision subscription key and endpoint
            const string subscriptionKey = "xxxxxxx";
            const string endpoint = @"https://xxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";

            const string readTextUrlImage = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxxxxxxx/view?usp=sharing";
            var client = Authenticate(endpoint, subscriptionKey);

            // Extract text (OCR) from a URL image using the Read 
            ReadFileUrl(client, readTextUrlImage).Wait();
        }
        
        public static ComputerVisionClient Authenticate(string endpoint, string key)
        {
            var client =
                new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(key))
                    { Endpoint = endpoint };
            return client;
        }

        public static async Task ReadFileUrl(ComputerVisionClient client, string urlFile)
        {
            try
            {
                var textHeaders = await client.ReadAsync(urlFile);
                // After the request, get the operation location (operation ID)
                var operationLocation = textHeaders.OperationLocation;
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                // Retrieve the URI where the extracted text will be stored from the Operation-Location header.
                // We only need the ID and not the full URL
                const int numberOfCharsInOperationId = 36;
                var operationId = operationLocation[^numberOfCharsInOperationId..];

                // Extract the text
                ReadOperationResult results;
                Console.WriteLine($"Extracting text from URL file {Path.GetFileName(urlFile)}...");
                Console.WriteLine();
                do
                {
                    results = await client.GetReadResultAsync(Guid.Parse(operationId));
                } while ((results.Status == OperationStatusCodes.Running ||
                          results.Status == OperationStatusCodes.NotStarted));

                // Display the found text.
                Console.WriteLine();
                var textUrlFileResults = results.AnalyzeResult.ReadResults;
                foreach (var page in textUrlFileResults)
                {
                    foreach (var line in page.Lines)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I will really apreciate any help on this!

Comment: A Bad request error(400) occurs when a request which has been sent to the website server is incorrect/mistyped or corrupt and if the server receiving the request fails to understand it.
There is a possibility that the URL which has been used in the code could be wrong/mistyped.
Re-check the URL in readTextUrlImage and provide the valid one

Comment: I had the exact same issue, while my url was correct. Using the [Cognitive services console] (https://centraluseuap.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005/console) I discovered that my image file size was too big, there was just a little more error detail available via the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A Bad request error(400) occurs when a request which has been sent to the website server is incorrect/mistyped or corrupt and if the server receiving the request fails to understand it.

- There is a possibility that the URL which has been used in the code could be wrong/mistyped.
- Re-check the URL in **readTextUrlImage** and provide the valid one.

```cs
const string readTextUrlImage = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxxxxxxx/view?usp=sharing";
```

- I have reproduced the same code with valid URL and got the expected result.

**Output:**
[image]